# Количество записей за текущий месяц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    types VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    dt DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

`types` - имеет значения *one* или *two*.

Нужно вывести записи за текущий месяц вида:

| id | К-во types_one | К-во types_two |

Моя наработка:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) 
  FROM `items` 
 WHERE MONTH(dt) = MONTH(NOW()) 
   AND YEAR(dt) = YEAR(NOW()) 
 GROUP BY `types`
```

Помогите пожалуйста в составлении данного запроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN types = 'one' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_ones,
       sum(CASE WHEN types = 'two' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_twos
  FROM `items` 
 WHERE MONTH(dt) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
   AND YEAR(dt) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Тут поле `ID` не получится выводит, так как вам нужно количество.

UPD:

если нужно по `title` будет так

```
SELECT title,
       sum(CASE WHEN types = 'one' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_ones,
       sum(CASE WHEN types = 'two' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_twos
  FROM `items` 
 WHERE MONTH(dt) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
   AND YEAR(dt) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
 GROUP BY title
 ORDER BY title
```

Comment: Выводит одну только запись, и с неправильным к-в. 
one -1, two - 2. Хотя two за это число нету в БД.

Comment: записей будет 1, так как на текушый месяц. И еще можете дать примерные данные для теста

Comment: да точно id не получится. В принципи оно и не нужно.

Comment: @depredator тестовые данные, структура другая

Comment: Да, ошибся. Вот http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a10e1

Comment: Похоже второй запрос Ваш верный.

Comment: @depredator проверил все работает правильно. в обоих случаех количество правильно

Comment: Да, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30851/discussion-between-depredator-and-saidolim).